# How can I make Apache Camel Routes faster?

Tags: java, performance, routes, apache-camel, asynchronous

What I would like to do is increase the speed of the routes, meaning I would like to achieve more routes being executed per second.

Can I run some of the 100 routes I am running right now at the same time on separate threads? If so, how do I do this?

I am running a plain route like this and gathering the starting and ending time of the main loop:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.builder.AdviceWithRouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class TestAdviceRoute extends AdviceWithRouteBuilder {


    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:start")
        .routeId("Doug")
        .process(new PrintProcessor())
        .end()
        ;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        System.out.println("Start Time:" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            context.addRoutes(new TestAdviceRoute());
            context.getRouteDefinition("Doug").adviceWith(context, new WrapRoute());

            context.createProducerTemplate().sendBody("direct:start", "Doug");
            context.stop();
        }
        System.out.println("End Time:" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }

}
```

Note: I have already checked out [Apache Camel - AsyncProcessing](http://camel.apache.org/asynchronous-processing.html) but I did not find this very helpful for increasing the speed of a single route. It did however allow for a reduced time when trying to run two different routes at the same time.

Comment: This question is waaay to open ended. Having multiple routes will consume multiple resources. What you need to do is profile your routes see where most time is being spent and then apply scaling techniques to it. For example splitting and streaming a large CSV file via splitter EIP using a thread pool. This is premature optimization.

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/seda.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are surely doing something bad and strange.

Some pointers

1. You should only stop the camel context once, and not for each loop.
2. Creating a producer template once and reuse it
3. Why are you advicing the route? Doing that causes the route to be restarted. Not sure what your point is.
4. Direct component is for synchrononous direct method invocation.

You can use seda with concurrent consumers if you want more threads to process messages from a single route.

Comment: Thank you! I will implement your suggestions.